# Why does the cursor have a tail?

Tags: design, cursor

Look at your cursor.

[image: cursor]

What's the purpose of its tail—the small rectangular portion at the bottom-right? To me, it follows that it would be equally useful without a tail. I can certainly see why its designers would choose a triangle-shaped body, but decision to tack on a tail remains an enigma to me.

Comment: There' s a long and interesting history of how the cursor was developed. Much of it, if I remember correctly, had to do with the limitations of early monitors.

Comment: because Paramont would sue for infringing Star Trek's copyright.

Comment: I did. It looks like this one: http://i.imgur.com/kecHpfR.jpg (first image I could find, mine is in HD). I am using it since the 90s.

Comment: Somewhat related, you'll notice many video games do have cursors that is just triangular, or just the arrowhead.

Comment: If the mouse is set up is too fast you don't see the mouse at all during movement.  If someone is just shaking the mouse (they do) there is a visual feedback.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

To add to DA01's great [answer](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/84408), here's [the history of cursor arrow](http://www.fastcodesign.com/3026625/why-the-mouse-cursor-is-tilted-instead-of-vertical).

The link also links to a [well known document from Xerox](http://bitsavers.trailing-edge.com/pdf/xerox/parc/techReports/VLSI-81-1_The_Optical_Mouse.pdf) with further explanation, from which I took the image below.

[image: Quadrature Encoding of Pointer Motion on a Bitmap Display System]

However, this document doesn't explain the reason behind the tail. This being said, the reasons for tilting explain why tilting was needed. Now I'll take the same image and take the tail out:

[image]

OK, now, where is the arrow pointing at? Keep in mind this was used in low resolution screens with bitmap pixel rendering. It's easy to see the tail solved this issue.

To add to the rendered digital representation, take a look to a [1972's Plato Terminal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrow_keys#Historical_development) keyboard:

[image: 1972's Plato Terminal keyboard detail]

Same goes for IBM keyboards (1981' Model F below):

[image: 1981' Model F keyboard]

If you take the tails off, you won't be able to tell where are the arrows pointing at, so this is also a digital representation of an analog process, a concept known as [skeuomorphism](https://www.techopedia.com/definition/28955/skeuomorphism) (also, see DA01's "indian" arrow where the concept of [Archetype](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archetype) is used).

Comment: +1 - Didn't even think about how the arrow tail provided a better direction indicator on otherwise ambiguous low resolution triangle, seems fairly obvious now.

Comment: You've taken out more than just the tail, you've also taken off the flanges on the side.

Comment: What the...? Vista's cursors had tails.

Comment: You had the no tails option in Vista, that list is taken from the available options in Vista's Aero, or do you think I made them up? As for @Random832 , you're correct, I just did a straight line cut, see  http://i.stack.imgur.com/9HWpT.png for a real size representation (at 72PPI!) of what a Mac Mono (pre-Lisa) would display.

Comment: @Devin I don't think _you_ made them up, but these appear to be the original creation of the DeviantArt user "yethzart" rather than factory-provided cursors from Microsoft.

Comment: ok, I edited to concentrate on what matters and avoid discussions

Comment: To nitpick...this isn't skeuomorphism. You don't interact with the arrow like you would an actual arrow. It's merely a representation.

Comment: In your particular case it's a representation or Archetype, as I mentioned. However, I'm talking about the cursor buttons on keyboards, so you're talking about digital representations taking cues from real world

Comment: @devin I agree. i don't agree with the Wikipedia definition of skeuomorphism, though. I think that term has been abused as of late and now means 'faux'

Comment: I argue a button is a skeuomorphism as it acts like a real button. A calculator UI is a skeuomorphism because it acts like a real calculator. An arrow icon, however doesn't act like a real arrow.

Comment: [Here](http://i.imgur.com/aC6i5A9.jpg) is a "correct" version IMO of the cursor from your answer with the tail removed, and "actual size" versions [with](http://i.imgur.com/lpIaqg4.png) and [without](http://i.imgur.com/1oFKnJ1.png) tail. I think they still support your point. The direction is discernable but barely.

Comment: @DasBeasto That happens so much "Why is ____" "Well, have you actually tried it without ____?"

Comment: I thought this was called "Mouse Pointer", and "Cursor" only refered to the thing indicating where the next character of text you type with a keyboard will appear...

Answer (score 57):

It's an arrow:

[image]

pictograms of arrows have mostly always had at least the arrow head and the shaft:

[image]

Whoever drew the cursor as we know it was drawing an arrow. It became the default standard.

You are right, it probably would work without the shaft (or tail) just as well. It's just that it's not what the UI designer chose when it was created and we've decided to stick with it.

Also, the pointer is uses as a cursor for your mouse, but it's also often needed to be shown as a tool (for example in software where the pointer is to select objects, but you use other cursors for other functions). For example, look at the toolbar on this early GUI (The Apple Lisa, which borrowed heavily from Xerox Parc's Alto):

[image]

Adding the tail makes it much more distinct as a tool icon than a plain triangle would be by itself.

DasBeasto provided an excellent link in the comments that talks about the design of the Alto Pointer:

http://www.fastcodesign.com/3026625/why-the-mouse-cursor-is-tilted-instead-of-vertical

It appears the designer was Douglas Engelbart and the angled arrow has a lot to do with the limited resolution of early GUIs. Steve Jobs and Bill Gates "borrowed" the idea and we've decided as a culture that it's simply the way mouse pointers are supposed to look forever more. :)

Comment: That works for me.

Comment: @MarcusMcLean I added a historical bit as well. It's more my opinion than 'fact' but seems plausible at least. :)

Comment: As for the "whoever drew the cursor" bit there's a little info [here](http://www.fastcodesign.com/3026625/why-the-mouse-cursor-is-tilted-instead-of-vertical) that says who. It also says it was an "arrow" pointing up lending credit to the fact he was just drawing a typical arrow.

Comment: @DasBeasto it was a pure guess on my part that the Alto was likely the earliest example. Based on your link, it looks like I guessed correctly. :)

Comment: Not to nit-pick, but did Xerox's system really have small apples all around its menus? Also an arrow with a stone or metal "arrowhead" might be more easy to relate to the arrow pictographs.

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen 'doh! I grabbed that screen shot and didn't double check the source. Let me investigate.

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen ah! That's the Lisa! I'll update the answer to clarify.

Comment: Going full circle, the article on fastcodesign.com cites an answer elsewhere on [UX.SE](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/52336/why-is-the-mouse-cursor-slightly-tilted-and-not-straight/52338#52338)

Comment: Your "pictograms of arrows" image contains two with no shaft (second column from the right)

Comment: @benvoigt that is correct (hence *mostly*)

Comment: which raises another interesting question as to why they chose an arrow. Fascinating to imagine what else might have been chosen. Perhaps a lecturer's cane? Thought that would be a pain to depict.

Comment: @theotherone I was thinking this as well, arrows for directional purposes make sense as it appear the "head" is moving along the "shaft" in the direction it's pointing, symbolizing movement. But arrows (neither the literal bow/arrow or the arrows found on keys) inherently symbolize pointing at something. My guess is it was just the "pointiest" thing they could find.

Comment: Arrows as direction tools existing long before the computer. They were extremely common in printed materials and signange and maps, etc. (as were pointing hands).

Comment: @DA01: Interestingly, arrows as direction tools are so far removed from the physical arrows (ammunition for a bow) nowadays, that it never occurred to me they actually depict the same thing. Accordingly, [some dictionaries](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/arrow) distinguish two different (albeit related) meanings, rather than just listing one meaning like "a weapon shot from a bow, depictions of which are also used as a direction mark".

Answer (score 6):

look at how your finger points it could also be a wrist. people also see based on shapes and the cursor as is has more breaks and easily stands out on top of pages than a triangle.

[image]

Also a right handed person pointing explains the direction of the cursor. Read more about it from the question [why the cursor is tilted and not straight](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/52336/why-is-the-mouse-cursor-slightly-tilted-and-not-straight?lq=1)

[image]

Comment: Yeah if you keep only the pointing finger, the whole thing becomes much less clear :d

Comment: The picture I saw years ago was a fist with just the index finder extended. But yes your right just the finger leaves a huge gap between it and the cursor. Also these were hypotheses that I have read i have never seen that it was confirmed to look like this. Though it was said as to why it points to the left rather than the right. Ie a rightys finger

Answer (score -2):

< works well but yeah it looks like a sideways V. The little rectangular chunk adds to the "arrow" effect to it. It looks less like an arrow and looks more like an image of an arrow. I agree with the other one about the Star Trek copyright issues but also consider that fed ex might have issues with the arrow as well.

http://www.toxel.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/06/logo09.jpg

Comment: What do you mean by "issues with the arrow"? FedEx being a transportation company, I would presume that the apparent arrow is *intentional*, given that arrows are quite sometimes used as a symbol for movement, transportation, and speed (cf. various railroad logos).

Comment: Simple geometric shapes are not protected by copyright; there are no Star Trek or FedEx copyright issues here. The FedEx logo is a trademark, but nobody's going to look at a mouse cursor and think that your operating system is a FedEx product or service, so there's no issue there either.

Comment: @TannerSwett: "nobody's going to look at (...) and think that your (...) is a (...) product or service" - [if only trademark lawyers thought in such reasonable ways](http://www.theguardian.com/world/2013/oct/07/apfelkind-cafe-trademark-battle-apple-germany) ;)