# Is there any working straight or reflected mouse cursor theme?

Tags: mouse, cursor, themes

OK, it's clear that [mouse cursor has it's shape by historical reasons](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/52336/why-is-the-mouse-cursor-slightly-tilted-and-not-straight). But since 1995, didn't anybody make usable straight or reflected mouse cursor? MS Word uses reflected mouse cursor sometimes. But it's really weird that even searching for straight cursor theme just answers why the cursor is not straight and doesn't provide any usable themes.

EDIT: I'm looking for a style or theme which **does** use straight or reflected mouse cursor, because sometimes I use left-handed mouse, and it's not convenient to keep it's shape as right-handed version.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking here. You say "theme", so are you asking about cursor style for a particular product? Or are you asking for examples of software that use "straight cursors"? Or are you asking for any reference documents that detail why cursors are commonly designed the way that they are?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is the mouse cursor slightly tilted and not straight?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/52336/why-is-the-mouse-cursor-slightly-tilted-and-not-straight)

Answer (score 1):

This is a really good question, something I've been asking myself too.
Some of the reasons why we are using this pointer are:

The angle is because we create the same angle when you are pointing at something that you see with your hand. This is because it's copying the real-life interaction that you usually do when following some text when you are reading a book.

[image]

Try following some text you reading and try to keep your hand straight and not angled, observe how uncomfortable can that be.

A really nice video about the cursor we currently use:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YThelfB2fvg&ab_channel=Posy